# Filter and extract only emails with a certain domainname

Tags: php, regex, email

I would like to know how to match certain emails (with requiered domainames) an exaple;

I would like to extract all email with the ending ".es" or ".pt", ".com.mx" etc... I've coded a little script to filter some emails; "hotmail.com", "aol.com", "gmail.com"...

```
  <?php

    $emails = $_POST['emails'];
    $ex     = explode("\n", $emails);
    $count  = count($ex);
    if (isset($emails) && $count >= 1) {
        echo "<center><font color = 'red'><b>$count </font>Number of emails  </b></center><br />";
    } else {
        echo "<center>  
    No email </center>";
        exit;
    }

    if (isset($emails)) {


        for ($i = 0; $i <= $count; $i++) {
            $d = strtolower($ex[$i]);

            if (strstr($d, "@hotmail") || strstr($d, "@live") || strstr($d, "@msn") || strstr($d, "@outlook")) {
                $hotmail .= $d;
                $nh = $nh + 1;
            } else {
                if (strstr($d, "@yahoo") || strstr($d, "@ymail")) {
                    $yahoo .= $d;
                    $ny = $ny + 1;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: `.*@.*?\.(es|pt|pt|com.mx)` Something like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `strstr()`, use regular expressions with [`preg_match_all()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_preg_match_all.htm). Your regular expression should look like `.+@.+\.((?:es)|(?:pt))` (Do not forget to complete it).